# Disable associations when a foreign key do not exist

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-relationship, entity-framework-6

I've created an edmx for my database. In it Entity framework removed a table and instead created an association between two tables because it matches a column name with the primary key in the other table.

I do not want that as there is no real association between those tables. How can I remove that association and get a class for the middle table instead?

Example:

**SomeTable**

- Id int pk

**MiddleTable**

- SomeTableId int fk
- SomeCode int

**OtherTable**

- SomeCode int pk

It's the `MiddleTable` which do not get a class.

Answer (score 0):

- Remove one table from the edmx, e.g. `OtherTable`.
- Update model from database and add `MiddleTable`.
- Update model from database and add `OtherTable`.

When I do this with a similar model I end up with an association between `SomeTable` and `MiddleTable` and an unassociated `OtherTable`. Now you can add/remove associations manually as you wish.

It's normal EF behavior not to create a class for the middle table. This is a so-called *many to many* association between `SomeTable` and `OtherTable` which can be modelled by two collection properties:

`SomeTable.OtherTables`
`OtherTable.SomeTables`

The middle table, the *junction table*, is not really necessary.

It's a bit surprising to me that you say that there is no association between the two tables although, apparently, in the database there are foreign keys. Technically, it *is* a many to many association.

Comment: It's not a junction table as it got no connection to othertable. EF shouldn't go and create associations without foreign keys.

Comment: OK, I didn't know it used name conventions like this in database-first, I thought FKs were leading. But does removing and updating the tables work?