# LINQ Join with EF Navigation Property

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq, entity-framework

I have read many things about how to use Entity Framework Navigation Properties in LINQ join statements and I am still having trouble.  I can make it work within Where clauses but not as a join.

Here is what my LINQ would look like if my cross reference table existed in EF and wasn't just a Navigation Property:

```
var status = (from a in context.Beamtime_Request_Statuses
              join b in context.Proposal_Types_Beamtime_Request_Statuses on a.Status equals b.Beamtime_Request_Status
              where b.Proposal_Type_ID == proposalTypeID && a.Order > currentStatusOrder
              orderby a.Order
              select a.Status).FirstOrDefault();
```

So the problem is that the table Proposal_Types_Beamtime_Request_Statuses does not become an Entity, only a Navigation Property because the table only contains the columns Proposal_Type_ID and Beamtime_Request_Status which are both primary keys of other tables and foreign keys in this table.

If someone can show me how to wrote that LINQ statement using the appropriate notation with Proposal_Types_Beamtime_Request_Statuses as a Navigation Property it would be much appreciated.

Comment: So `Beamtime_Request_Status` has a property `Proposal_Types`?

Comment: Yes Beamtime_Request_Statuses has a Navigation Property of Proposal_Types and Proposal_Types has a Navigation Property of Beamtime_Request_Statuses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're having a many-to-many association with a pure junction table (only two foreign keys, both comprising the table's primary key). By default, Entity Framework doesn't map such tables to a class. You can leave it this way and query the many-to-many association like so:

```
from a in context.Beamtime_Request_Statuses
where a.Proposal_Types.Any(pt => pt.Proposal_Type_ID == proposalTypeID)
   && a.Order ... (rest of the query)
```

(Assuming that `Beamtime_Request_Status` has a property `Proposal_Types`, as EF would create by default.)

Or you can force EF to map the table as a class. [Here's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22024066/861716) an approach that should work. You can also add a column to the junction table, update the model from the database and remove the column again (or leave it there if it happens to be a useful column).

Comment: Thank you!  So the where clause essentially replicates what the join would do if that cross reference table were actually available as an entity.

Comment: Yes, you'll see that when you inspect the generated SQL.